# Inequality with heterogeneous functions

Tags: calculus

I need to prove that

$$2^n - n! \leq 0.$$

How do I calculate (without hit and trial) the value of $n$ ?

Comment: what have you done??

Comment: In this case, trial and error finding of suitable smallest $n$, together with proof that the inequality holds from then on, is the best strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a proof by induction starting with $n=4$. When $n=4$, we have $2^4=16 < 4!=24$ so the inequality holds.  Next, suppose that $2^n \leq n!$.  Then multiplying both sides of this inequality by two, we find $2^{n+1}\leq 2\cdot n! \leq (n+1) n! = (n+1)!$ which completes the proof.

Comment: $2^1\gt 1!$; $2^2\gt 2!$; $2^3\gt 3!$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $n \in \mathbb{N}$

$2 < n$ $\forall$ $n > 2$.

That gives $2.3.4. \dots .n > 2.2.2. \dots n (n$-times)

So $n! > 2^n$

So $n! - 2^n > 0$

Equality occurs for $n = 0$

So it is done.